# It it possible to create a global lambda error metric/alarm with CDK L2 constructs

Tags: aws-cdk

I have an alarm for any error across all lambda functions. The L1 for this is:

```
    const errorAlarm = new CfnAlarm(this, 'CloudWatchAlarm', {
      alarmName: "AllErrors",
      alarmDescription: "Lambda error alarm",
      actionsEnabled: true,
      metricName: "Errors",
      namespace: "AWS/Lambda",
      statistic: "Average",
      period: 300,
      evaluationPeriods: 1,
      datapointsToAlarm: 1,
      threshold: 1,
      comparisonOperator: "GreaterThanThreshold",
      treatMissingData: "missing",
      alarmActions:[notifyTopic.topicArn]    
    });
```

However I am not figuring out how/if I can turn this into an L2. It requires a logGroup for `MeticFilter`. Not finding much in docs for this.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was making this more difficult than necessary. Turns out I don't need a metric filter so no log group issue.  Here's the L2:

```
const errorMetric = new Metric({
  namespace: 'AWS/Lambda',
  metricName: 'Errors',
  dimensionsMap: {
    //   ProcessName: 'LoanProcessor',
  }
})

const errAlarm = new Alarm(this, 'ErrorAlarm', {
  metric: errorMetric,
  threshold: 1,
  evaluationPeriods: 1,
  datapointsToAlarm: 1,
  alarmName: 'AllErrors',
  alarmDescription: 'Lambda error alarm',
  actionsEnabled: true,
  comparisonOperator: ComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO_THRESHOLD
})

errAlarm.addAlarmAction(new SnsAction(notifyTopic))
```